# Is "For + Verb" correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

I know that we use "To + Verb" and "For + Verb-ing". But I heard this in a talk show(below) and I have been wondering whether it is right or not.

> My muscles are not **for show**, they are for my survival.

If this is correct, could you please give a explanation about this type of syntax? And what about this one?

> My muscles are not **for showing**, they are for my survival.

Comment: *For show* is a set phrase. You can't use your knowledge of this phrase to conclude anything else about English grammar. It's not even clear which word category the *show* in *for show* belongs to, although it looks like a noun. Your second sentence is OK---a bit more natural would be *my muscles are not for showing off*---but it doesn't really have anything to do with the first sentence grammatically.

Comment: [**Show**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/show) can be either a verb or a noun.  In this case, it's a noun meaning "an impressive display".

Comment: @legatrix  your comment really should be an answer. I wanted to answer this, but any good answer I could give would largely repeat your comment.

Comment: I would say that "for show" is a fixed noun phrase meaning "for purposes of display, and not for function" it is often contrasted with "for use".

Comment: @DavidSiegel Oh, thanks. I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For show* is a set phrase. You can't use your knowledge of this phrase to conclude anything else about English grammar. It's not even clear which word category the *show* in *for show* belongs to, although it looks like a noun. Your second sentence is OK---a bit more natural would be *my muscles are not for showing off*---but it doesn't really have anything to do with the first sentence grammatically.

Note: Others have suggested that *show* in *for show* is a noun, and this would certainly be my first instinct, too. I was trying to suggest, though, that since *for show* is a set phrase (a '[syntactic nut](http://eecoppock.info/CoppockThesis4.pdf)' in the sense of Culicover), we can't use it to conclude much about the syntax, and hence we can't know for sure that it's a noun.